# XSL - Make all node values with namespace available in CDATA sections

Tags: xslt

I am looking for XSL to transform provided input to expected output.I have just provided sample but actual input xml had more than 1000 nodes and as too many nodes not able to use CDATA section in XSL, could you please help.

**Input:**

```
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

**Output:**

```
<note>
   <to><![CDATA[Tove]]></to>
   <from><![CDATA[Jani]]></from>
   <heading><![CDATA[Reminder]]></heading>
   <body><![CDATA[Don't forget me this weekend!]]></body>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `cdata-section-elements` attribute of the `xsl:output` element which specifies all the elements that should be output in `CDATA` sections.

So use the following XSLT-1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" cdata-section-elements="to from heading body" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See that the `cdata-section-elements` denotes the elements `to from heading body` to enclose their content in a `CDATA` section. The *identity template* just copies all of the file with regard to this.

---

If your elements are in a namespace, you have to prefix the element's names in the `cdata-section-elements` with the appropriate namespace-prefix.

For example, if you have the following XML with a namespace on the root element, all children nodes are in that namespace, too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bank xmlns="http://xxyy.x.com" Operation="Create">
  <Customer type="random">
    <CustomerId>Id10</CustomerId>
    <CountryCode>CountryCode19</CountryCode>
    <LanguageCode>LanguageCode20</LanguageCode>
    <AddressArray>
      <Address type="primary">
        <StreetAddress>179 Alfred St</StreetAddress>
        <City>Fortitude Valley</City>
        <County>GR</County>
        <Country>India</Country>
      </Address>
    </AddressArray>
  </Customer>
</Bank>
```

Use this XSLT (pay attention to the namespace declaration on the `xsl:stylesheet` element):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://xxyy.x.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="ns0:CustomerId ns0:CountryCode ns0:LanguageCode ns0:StreetAddress ns0:City ns0:County ns0:Country" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Make sure that the namespace of the XSLT matches the namespace of the XML, here both are `http://xxyy.x.com`, but in your sample XML it is `xxyy.x.com`.

---

**EDIT 2:**

If you have a large amount of elements you can either add them all to `cdata-section-elements` (maybe by constructing it by another stylesheet) or use the solution I found here: [Wrapping all elements in CDATA](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200404/msg00665.html). It is kind of a hack.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"  omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:variable name="CDATABegin" select="'&lt;![CDATA['" />
    <xsl:variable name="CDATAEnd" select="']]&gt;'" />

    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()[normalize-space()]">
      <xsl:value-of select="$CDATABegin" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="$CDATAEnd" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This wraps all non-empty `text()` nodes in CDATA sections. But here, too, you'd have to mention all elements in template matching rules containing the CDATA wrapping code.

Which variant would be easier to apply depends on the greater scenario.

Comment: Thanks..sure, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Hi , I tried with provided xslt but output is not displayed with CDATA

Comment: Hi , I tried with provided xslt but output is not displayed with CDATA, I am using Oracle XDK XSLT processor.

Comment: sorry for multiple comments, below is my concern, For sample input it is working whereas payload in next comment section which is close to my realtime is not working, could you please help me on this.

Comment: <Bank xmlns="http://xxyy.x.com" Operation="Create">
  <Customer type="random">
      <CustomerId>Id10</CustomerId>     
      <CountryCode>CountryCode19</CountryCode>
      <LanguageCode>LanguageCode20</LanguageCode>    
      <AddressArray>
         <Address type="primary">
            <StreetAddress>179 Alfred St</StreetAddress>
            <City>Fortitude Valley</City>
            <County>GR</County>
            <Country>India</Country>
         </Address>    
      </AddressArray>
  </Customer>
</Bank>

Comment: Now one answered, question is still open

Comment: I added another solution.

Comment: The first answer is correct. DOE feature is not mandatory for an XSLT Processor implementation.